# How to display complex data in MVP Passive View

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, mvp

I've been looking in the MVP pattern for a while, and managed to create some simple MVP-compliant applications.

I am now trying to apply the pattern to a more complex application, and I have some doubts on the best way of doing that.

My application has a single WinForm, with two buttons for loading two different kinds of data. My view interface looks like the following:

```
interface IView_MainForm
{
    //  Load input
    //
    event EventHandler<InputLoadEventArgs> LoadInput_01;
    event EventHandler<InputLoadEventArgs> LoadInput_02;

    bool Input01_Loaded { get; set; }
    bool Input02_Loaded { get; set; }
}
```

The IView is referenced in my presenter via constructor injection:

```
public Presenter_MainForm(IView_MainForm view)
{
    this.View = view;
    this.View.LoadInput_01 += new EventHandler<InputLoadEventArgs>(OnLoadInput_01);
    this.View.LoadInput_02 += new EventHandler<InputLoadEventArgs>(OnLoadInput_02);
}
```

So far, so good. When the user clicks any of the two buttons for loading data, a LoadInput_## event is raised, the Presenter is handling it, checks the input for errors and structures it according to my data model.

My next step would be displaying the processed data back in the View.

I'm striving to keep my View as passive and "dumb" as possible, assuming it knows nothing of the Presenter (it doesn't subscribe to its events, the Presenter sends data to the View by calling IView methods instead), let alone of the Model.

How am I supposed to populate a control like a TreeView, if the View has no idea of what the data model looks like?

Also, am I getting the whole MVP thing right, or is there anything I have missed?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Does your view (Form) implements the `IView_MainForm` ?

Comment: If your `view` won't know what's the `data model` (I'm assuming you mean `Model`), how it is supposed to bind itself to data?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, got it, thanks.
@huMptyduMpty, yes, my view (`MainForm`) implements `IView_MainForm`, this is how I've been able to implement the MVP pattern at a basic level for now: `Presenter` takes `IView_MainForm` as parameter in its constructor, subscribes to its events and displays results by calling methods specified in the interface (and implemented by `MainForm`).

Comment: @michaelmoore that's exactly the question. As far as I understand, in MVP(PV) `View` and `Model` know nothing about each other, since it's the `Presenter` which handles user events and instructs the `View` on how to display data. If my `View` already knows what my data looks like, what's the point of MVP in the first place? I could then simply populate my controls by directly referencing my `Model`... Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with having `complex type` properties in your `View`. Let's say you have some `ComplexType`.

```
class ComplexType
{
   public string ParentNode {get;set;}
   public List<string> ChildNodes {get;set;}
   // some other properties
}
```

Let's also assume `ComplexType` is data model for your `TreeView`. It is perfectly fine with `MVP` pattern to have properties on your `View` that will have `ComplexType`. So having something like this is perfectly fine

```
interface IView_MainForm
{
    //  Load input
    //
    event EventHandler<InputLoadEventArgs> LoadInput_01;
    event EventHandler<InputLoadEventArgs> LoadInput_02;

    bool Input01_Loaded { get; set; }
    bool Input02_Loaded { get; set; }

    ComplexType Input01Data {get;set;} // you might actually have some code in get/set setters
    ComplexType Input02Data {get;set;} // you might actually have some code in get/set setters

    public void SetInput01Data(ComplexType input01Data)
    {
       Input01Data = input01Data;
       // some other stuff
    }
}
```

And since your `Model` is for `View` that has 2 inputs, your Model could look something like this

```
public interface IModel
{
   public ComplexType Input01Data {get;set;}
   public ComplexType Input02Data {get;set;}
}
```

Now in your `Presenter` you would just handle event fired from `View`, populate `Model` and set properties on `View`

```
class Presenter
{
    private IModel _myModel...
    private IRepository _repository;
    public Presenter(IView_MainForm view, IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        this.View = view;
        this.View.LoadInput_01 += new EventHandler<InputLoadEventArgs>(OnLoadInput_01);
        this.View.LoadInput_02 += new EventHandler<InputLoadEventArgs>(OnLoadInput_02);
    }

    public void OnLoadInput_01(object sender, InputLoadEventArgs e)
    {
         // get data based on passed arguments (e.SomeProperty)
         // construct IModel
         myModel = _repository.GetData(e.SomeProperty);
         // pass data to IView_MainForm
         View.SetInput01Data(myModel.Input01Data);
     }
}
```

And regarding your concern

> I'm striving to keep my View as passive and "dumb" as possible,
>   assuming it knows nothing of the Presenter (it doesn't subscribe to
>   its events, the Presenter sends data to the View by calling IView
>   methods instead), let alone of the Model.

Your `View` still doesn't know anything about `Presenter` nor `Model`. It just fires events, get data from `Presenter` and binds its controls. And you have `testability` in place (please note this Unit Test is pseudo code, since I don't know how you retrieve data, what input you required in button click event etc...) .

```
[Test]
public void ShouldLoadInput01DataOnButtonClick()
{
   // Arrange
   IModel data = // create dummy data

   Mock<IView_MainForm> clientsViewMock = new  Mock<IView_MainForm>();
   Mock<IRepository> clientsRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository>();

   clientsRepositoryMock.Setup(repository => repository.GetData(something)).Returns(data.Input01Data);     
   var presenter = new Presenter(clientsViewMock.Object, clientsRepositoryMock .Object);

   // Act
   clientsViewMock.Raise(view => view.LoadInput01 += null, new InputLoadEventArgs());

   // Assert
   clientsViewMock.Verify(view => view.SetInput01Data(data.Input01Data), "Input01 data expected be set on button click.");
}
```